# RandomAccessFile reading wrong Integers

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

So i'm using a `RandomAccessFile` to write data into a file.
Since i'm compressing the written data with lz4 first write the uncompressed size as an integer in the file, then the compressed size as integer and finally the compressed byte array. However, when reading the two integers something completely different comes out. I wrote a simple test and these are the results:

```
    int test = 982364567;

    System.out.println("Writing " + test + " in file...");

    this.clusterData.seek(1);
    this.clusterData.write(test);

    this.clusterData.seek(1);
    System.out.println("Reading " + this.clusterData.readInt() + " from file...");
```

`clusterData` is the RandomAccessFile and the output in the console is this:

```
Writing 982364567 in file...
Reading -1761607680 from file...
```

Could someone explain to me what is going wrong and what i'm missing there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be ware that `write(int data)` means write a `byte` represented by data. Therefore it will write a single byte.

You need to use the `writeInt(int data)` in order to write the full integer.